# google analytics report for desktop and mobile site

Tags: google-analytics, report, multiple-domains, google-analytics-filters

Is there a way to create like a piechart or report that distinguishes who have been on the m. or www. site of a domain?
both sites uses the same GA code.

I looked at cross domain tracking option and added a new filter as suggested but was unable to apply it to any reports on the GA account. Plus it will only show me the page list etc 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en

I want to know if i can just get a number on how many vistors on the m.mysite.com and www.mysite.com  websites during a date range

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: You do not need cross domain tracking to track subdomains, but you should be able to filter by the hostname field - not via the view filter (which might still be a good idea) but by setting it as secondary dimension (then you can apply an ad hoc filter in the data table), by creating segments based on hostname or by creating custom reports with a filter by hostname. Not really a programming question, though, so follow-ups should maybe go to webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know where i could set this up? Having trouble finding it on GA.